# c string isn't added to string correctly and outputs □ when using printf

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I've been programming a script where a string should be added to a string.
But the printf function in my code prints the first time `□` the second time `□□` and the third time `□□□`. It should print `A`,`Ap`, `App`.
Here's a quick overview of my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int i = 0;
char * name[];
char * tok[];
int hello = 0;

void append(char* s, char c) {
        int len = strlen(s);
        s[len] = c;
        s[len+1] = '\0';
}

int input(char data[]){
    for(i=0; i<strlen(data); ++i){
        append(tok, data[i]);
        if(hello == 0){
            append(name, tok);
            strcpy(tok, "");
            printf(name);
            printf("\n");
        }
   }
return 0;
}

int main(){
    input("App");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no storage associated with tok or name. they are just a pointers to a character arrays.

Comment: Try making tok and name have actual storage like: char tok[16], name[16]. Also, what is the function of 'hello'?

Comment: @Level42 in the real script tok is a variable. Only in the case above (the if statement) tok is one. Name is also variable because of input("this could be a long long text"). So I can't give them a storage.

Comment: By "real script" do you mean your real code? If you're unwilling to post the _exact_ code (an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not necessarily your exact code) that reproduces the problem, it becomes very difficult to help you. Nobody here is a mind reader or looking over your shoulder.

Comment: If you don't know how much memory you'll need until runtime, then you need to dynamically allocate with [`malloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) or something similar. If `name` and `tok` are only single strings, their types should be `char*` instead.

Comment: @yano the script above is representing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program has undefined behavior.

These tentative definitions

```
char * name[];
char * tok[];
```

in fact are equivalent to

```
char * name[1] = { NULL };
char * tok[1] = { NULL };
```

So for example this statement

```
int len = strlen(s);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Or the function first parameter

```
void append(char* s, char c) {
```

and the supplied argument

```
append(tok, data[i]);
```

have different types. The type of the argument is `char **` while the type of the parameter is `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int i = 0;
char name[99];
char tok[99];
int hello = 0;

void append(char *s, char c) {
        int len = strlen(s);
        s[len] = c;
        s[len+1] = '\0';
}

int input(char *data){
    for(i=0; i<strlen(data); ++i)
    {
        append(tok, data[i]);
        printf(tok);
        printf("\n");
     }

return 0;
}

int main(){
    input("App");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tok should get reseted after every letter. Also the result should get "saved" in an other variable like my example above

Comment: Your stated objective was "It should print A,Ap, App." The code above does it.

Comment: It should get printed over the variable name in my script above, thx